# How to make multiple innerHTML javascript statements more DRY

Tags: javascript

I am overwriting some HTML code via javascript in a Contact7 email form.

I have 3 "p" tags and I can't figure out a way to make this more DRY.

Here is my code

```
  //remove default HTML//
  document.querySelector('.wpcf7-response-output').innerHTML = '';
  
  //Add first p tag and text//
  var p1 = document.createElement('p');
  p1.innterHTML ="Thank you for your order!";
  document.querySelector('.wpcf7-response-output').appendChild(p1);
  
  //Add second p tag and text//
  var p2 = document.createElement('p');
  p2.innerHTML = "A confirmation email has been sent to you from info@iscafit.com.";
  document.querySelector('.wpcf7-response-output').appendChild(p2);
  
  //Add third p tag and text//
  var p3 = document.createElement('p');
  p3.innerHTML = "Please keep the confirmation email for your records."
  document.querySelector('.wpcf7-response-output').appendChild(p3);
```

The resulting html should be

```
<div class=".wpcf7-response-output">
  <p>Thank you for your order!</p>
  <p>A confirmation email has been sent to you from info@iscafit.com.</p>
  <p>Please keep the confirmation email for your records.</p>
</div>
```

I am a junior developer trying to get better at writing DRY code. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function instead that you can call with the text of a `p` to append:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-response-output');
container.innerHTML = '';
const append = (text) => {
  container.appendChild(document.createElement('p')).textContent = text;
};
append('Thank you for your order!');
append('A confirmation email has been sent to you from info@iscafit.com.');
append('Please keep the confirmation email for your records.');
```

Or just assign the new HTML string:

```
document.querySelector('.wpcf7-response-output').innerHTML = `
  <p>Thank you for your order!</p>
  <p>A confirmation email has been sent to you from info@iscafit.com.</p>
  <p>Please keep the confirmation email for your records.</p>
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You can remove repetition this way While keeping your function generalized.

The ability to generalize helps greatly in reducing code. appendChild function below can be used not only for this parent-child combination but any other parent-child combination as well.

'''

```
function appendChild(parentSelector,childTagname,innerhtml)
  {  
      var childel = document.createElement(childTagname);
      childel.innterHTML =innerhtml;
      document.querySelector(parentSelector).appendChild(childel);  
  }
  
  appendChild('.wpcf7-response-output','p',"Thank you for your order!");
  appendChild('.wpcf7-response-output','p',"A confirmation email has been sent to you from info@iscafit.com.");
  appendChild('.wpcf7-response-output','p',"Please keep the confirmation email for your records");
```

'''

Comment: This is such a great idea. I marked the other answer since I used that in my code, but this method is something that I will implement down the road if I have more appendChild requirements